# Create a for loop to generate a range of ViewModel @Published properties in Swift to match the CoreData model

Tags: swift, mvvm, core-data

The DataModel contains amongst other attributes 27 attributes (Int16) with names of qq1, qq2, ... qq27.  It seems silly to initialise each one in the ViewModel individually if we could use a for loop.  So, I tried an init(), but the @Published wrapper must be a property of a class.  I tried calling a function from the initialisation with various permutations, but it doesn't seem that we can call a function from within the initialisation.  It's no big deal - I could just list all 27 in the initialisation, but it's ugly and can't be efficient.  Does anyone have a solution?  The relevant code snippet showing both attempts, below:

```
class OpportunityViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var opportunityName = ""
    @Published var opportunityDescription = ""
    @Published var opportunityEstimatedValue: Int32 = 0
    @Published var opportunityDead = false
    @Published var opportunityCreated: Date = Date()
    @Published var opportunityUpdated: Date = Date()
    @Published var qualifier(qualifiers) = 0
    @Published var qq1 = 0 // This should be the result, but for qq1...qq27
    @Published var opportunityItem: OpportunityEntity!
    
    init() {
        var q = ""
        for qualifier in 1...27 {
             q = String("qq" + "\(qualifier)")
            @Published var q = 0
        }
    }
    
    func qualifiers () -> String {
        for qualifier in 1...27 {
             return String("qq" + "\(qualifier)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn’t directly answer the question. But it seems like the wrong modeling. Why not using an array attribute? Dynamically allocation of attributes/properties in swift is kind of funky.

Comment: Thank you, it was my original intention to use array attributes, but it didn't seem at the time that CoreData supported these.  Let me do some digging.

Comment: CoreData support arrays